# Remember the state of extjs 4 checkbox

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

In my form panel I added a checkbox, setting:

```
stateful: true,
stateId: 'loginPanelRemeberMe'
```

then, before sending form I save state calling:

```
this.saveState()
```

on the panel. All other componenets save their state and whe I reload the page they recall the previous state, but checkbox alway start in unchecked state.
Is there any way to force save value?

Comment: Question title mentions a combobox, but question body is actually about checkboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

In your Application launch function (or in a controller init function), add the following:

```
if( Ext.supports.LocalStorage )
{
    Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider());
}
else
{
    Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());
}
```

Then define your checkbox in a view and override the getState and applyState functions:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
    getState: function() {
        return { "checked": this.getValue() };
    },
    applyState: function(state) {
        this.setValue( state.checked );
    },
    stateEvents: [
        'change'
    ],
    stateId: 'myCheckBox',
    stateful: true,
    id: 'myCheckBox',
}
```

Tested to work with ExtJS 4.2 and 6.5.x.

**Note for Sencha Architect users:**
If you defined a view as your initial view, a hidden Ext.create line like `Ext.create('YourApp.view.MainPanel')` is added automatically by Sencha Architect on top of your launch function. That will have the undesirable effect of instantiating your view **before** your state provider can be initialized, and so your fields applyState function will never get called.

**Solution:** un-mark your view as the initial view, and add the Ext.create line manually **after** your state provider is initialized.

Comment: Still works for Ext JS 5.1.3, except, click and check aren't events, so I only needed `change`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is this:
I ovverrided state function of panel, and added a checkbox status field.
    //Management of checkbox state
    rememberMe: false,

```
getState: function() {
    var state = this.callParent();
    state = this.addPropertyToState(state, 'rememberMe', this.rememberMe);
    return state;
},

applyState: function(state) {
    this.callParent(state);
    this.getComponent('checkRememberMe').setValue(state.rememberMe);
},
```

and in the method who submit the form I've added the following rows:

```
//Manage state
var checkRememberMe = this.getComponent('checkRememberMe'); 
if(checkRememberMe.getValue() == true){
    this.rememberMe = checkRememberMe.getValue();
    this.saveState();
}
```